# Ubuntu 16.04 on VMWare Workstation 14, shows in tab view, but no console!

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I have set up Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on workstation 14 pro. When I power it on, in the TAB view I see that the system is starting and then the starting page of Ubuntu, waiting for password

[image: The tab view of Ubuntu 16.04]

But when I switch to the console view to start using Ubuntu, there is nothing there. Blank, black page, as below, without any error, or any access!!

[image: console view for Ubuntu, nothing!]

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the machine settings to remove the CD/DVD drive and possibly any other virtual SATA device (the virtual hard disk likely was installed as a SCSI device regardless of how your physical disk(s) is attached).

Then reboot.  Then shutdown and re-add them.

I had the exact same problem on first boot of Ubuntu 16.04 under VMware Workstation 14.1.1 following "easy install".  I had to forcibly power off the VM.  When I powered it back on Workstation threw up a dialog complaining that there was no physical device to back SATA 0:1 (the CD/DVD).